# Getting sizeof(MyClass) in class member declaration

Tags: c++, static, sizeof

I am working in embedded C++ project, where I plan to make memory statically allocated as much as I can. So, I am writing a set of functions to override new/delete for all classes and for the global new/delete.

Here is a naive implementation:

```
class MyClass
{
    int x;
    float y;
    double z;

    static MyClass m_preAllocatedObjects[100];  //Solution 1
    static char m_preAllocatedMemory[100 * sizeof(MyClass)]; //Solution 2
    static char* getPreAllocatedMemory() // Solution 3
    {
        static char localStaticMemory[100 * sizeof(MyClass)];
        return localStaticMemory;
    }

    static void* operator new(size_t s){ 
     void* p; /*fill p from the pre-allocated memory or object*/;
     return p;
    }
};
```

**Solution 1**: It works for object with default constructor only.

**Solution 2**: It gives compilation error `use of undefined type 'MyClass'`; and ***this is what I am asking about***.

**Solution 3**: This solution works fine.

The question is:

Why can I create static members of MyClass, while I can't get sizeof(MyClass)?

Comment: You can create a static array of pointers to your object and allocate with whatever constructor you want. A static vector of unique_ptr would be best, as it will delete automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> while I can't get sizeof(MyClass)?

The reason is that `MyClass` is not fully defined until the closing `}` of the class definition, from section *9 Classes* of the c++11 standard (draft n3337):

> A class-name is inserted into the scope in which it is declared immediately after the class-name is seen.
>   The class-name is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the injected-class-name.
>   For purposes of access checking, the injected-class-name is treated as if it were a public member name. A
>   class-specifier is commonly referred to as a class definition. **A class is considered defined after the closing
>   brace of its class-specifier has been seen** even though its member functions are in general not yet defined.
>   The optional attribute-specifier-seq appertains to the class; the attributes in the attribute-specifier-seq are
>   thereafter considered attributes of the class whenever it is named.

and `sizeof` can only be applied to a complete type, from section *5.3.3 Sizeof*:

> The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand. The operand is
>   either an expression, which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), or a parenthesized type-id. **The sizeof
>   operator shall not be applied to an expression that has** function or **incomplete type**, to an enumeration
>   type whose underlying type is not fixed before all its enumerators have been declared, to the parenthesized
>   name of such types, or to an lvalue that designates a bit-field. ...

To correct, define the size of the array outside of the class definition:

```
class MyClass
{
    static char m_preAllocatedMemory[];
};

char MyClass::m_preAllocatedMemory[100 * sizeof(MyClass)];
```

Answer (score 3):

To "know" the size of `MyClass` the compiler will need to know the whole class. When you are forward declaring a `static MyClass m_preAllocatedObjects[100];` you are actually not defining the variable - to actually get the variable, you will have to do :

```
MyClass MyClasss::m_preAllocatedObjects[100];
```

somewhere in a .cpp file. This is where the memory for the objects are being "placed" as a lump in the data-segment. So the compiler doesn't have to know the actual size of `MyClass` at the point where you declare the variable. However, it does need to know the size to evaluate `100 * sizeof(MyClass)`.

Comment: Then,the compiler should also "know" the whole type before creating an array of that type? Why "static MyClass m_preAllocatedObjects[100]" works with no issues?

Comment: Like I said, the actual static array isn't "created" until later on when you define it in a .cpp file (or in a .h file, as long as you only have it ONCE in the whole program).

Answer (score 2):

You have to do that in two step:

- declaring an array (without knowing its size) inside the class.
- defining it, after you finish declaring the class, so that you know the size.

Here is the code:

```
class MyClass
{
     int x;
     ...
     static char m_preAllocatedMemory[];
};


char MyClass::m_preAllocatedMemory[100 * sizeof(MyClass)];
```